# Internet sharing not working after one hop

Tags: wireless, internet

I have a broadband ADSL connection to a modem router. I have connected this router 'A' to another wifi-modem router 'B' through a LAN cord.

Internet works fine in windows with wifi connection.

However, in linux (Android, Fedora, Ubuntu) it connects to the wifi network but I am not able to use internet.

Please note that all settings are automatic DHCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that both routers A and B were acting as DHCP servers assigning same range of IP addresses. I disabled DHCP on router B and everything started working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well few things can be a problematic here...

- Is there any packet filter/MAC filter/firewall?
- Does Linux get the same address pool as Windows?
- Do you have a connection (i.e., do pings work) between Linux and Windows, Linux and router B, Linux and router A?
- Could you please copy/paste `ifconfig -a`?